# How to terminate any ip/ip tunnel which has this host as destination

Tags: cisco, route, tunneling, ifconfig, cisco-nexus

I am in a situation where I want to terminate any tunnels at one device. I.e. I want to be able to create a tunnel to this device from any source ip adress.

Something which can inspect a packet, see that it is a tunnel (IP-in-IP or GRE works fine for me) destined for this host, strip of the outer header and forward it by the inner header would be fine for my purposes.

I would suggestions both which are doable within Linux or/and with a Cisco Nexus 3000 device.

Are there any support for this?

---

Example:

Suppose Alice wants to send a packet to Bob. Suppose Carol has such a terminate-any-tunnel capability described above.

Alice could then send the following packet

```
# Outer IP header
Dest: Carol
Source: Alice
# Inner IP header
Dest: Bob
Source: Alice
# Payload
```

Carol will check that the packet is destined for her, strip off the outer header and route the remaining packet with the default routing rules.

```
# IP header
Dest: Bob
Source: Alice
# Payload
```

Note that we did not have to configure anything specific on Carol's side (other than initially).

Comment: I think you just described a NAT.

Comment: Actually, I see it more as the description of a MITM attack.